# c# unit test fails with moq when it goes to hit a real service

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

So I was put on doing unit test and i noticed different unit tests failing in nunit and in Visual Studio with Resharper i tried debugging it and I get object

```
   [Test]
    public void KeyDocumentService_ProofKeyDocument_RepoReturnsData_ServiceReturnsTheDataWithoutError()
    {
        //Arrange
        KeyDocumentProofRequest request = new KeyDocumentProofRequest() { KeyDocumentId = 2 };
        string returnedResponse = "2";
        KeyDocument keyDocumentResponse = new KeyDocument() { CampaignId = "2", DesignFileId = 3,DocumentId="2", DataSourceId="3", KeyDocumentId=1 };
        List<vwKeyDocumentSearch> keyListResponse = new List<vwKeyDocumentSearch>() { new vwKeyDocumentSearch { FieldName = "test", FieldValue = "testvalue" } };
        var uproduceRepo = new Mock<IUProduceRepository>();
        var keyDocRepo = new Mock<IKeyDocumentRepository>();
        var templateRepo = new Mock<ITemplateRepository>();
        keyDocRepo.Setup(p => p.GetKeyDocument(It.IsAny<KeyDocumentRequest>())).Returns(new KeyDocumentResponse() { data = keyDocumentResponse });
        keyDocRepo.Setup(p => p.GetKeyDocumentItems(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(keyListResponse);
        uproduceRepo.Setup(p => p.ProduceDocument(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Customization[]>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), null)).Returns(returnedResponse);
        // Act.
        KeyDocumentService svc = new KeyDocumentService(keyDocRepo.Object, uproduceRepo.Object, templateRepo.Object);
        var response = svc.ProofKeyDocument(request);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(response);
        Assert.IsNotNull(response.data.JobId);
        Assert.IsNull(response.Error);
    }
```

So the error is happening on this line :

`var response = svc.ProofKeyDocument(request);`

Are unit Tests supposed to even be going into a real service?  or is that ok?

That Method `ProofKeyDocument`  looks like this  FYI

```
    private List<Customization> GetCustomizationsFromKeyDocumentItems(List<vwKeyDocumentSearch> keyDocumentItemsList,
                                        int templateId, int clientId)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Customization> KeyDocumentCustomizations = new List<Customization>();

            var keyDocumentVariableList = keyDocumentItemsList.Where(k => k.Type.ToUpper()=="VARIABLE").ToList();
            var keyDocumentSettingList = keyDocumentItemsList.Where(k => k.Type.ToUpper() == "SETTING").ToList();
            var keyDocumentContentList = keyDocumentItemsList.Where(k => k.Type.ToUpper() == "CONTENT").ToList();

            KeyDocumentCustomizations.AddRange(VariableCustomizations(keyDocumentVariableList, templateId));
            KeyDocumentCustomizations.AddRange(SettingCustomizations(keyDocumentSettingList, templateId));
            KeyDocumentCustomizations.AddRange(ContentCustomizations(keyDocumentContentList, templateId, clientId));

            return KeyDocumentCustomizations;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(string.Format("Error customizing key document: {0}", templateId), ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I see with Debugging it blowing up on this line
`var keyDocumentVariableList = keyDocumentItemsList.Where(k => k.Type.ToUpper()=="VARIABLE").ToList();`

**Object Reference not set to instance... error**    Why ?

```
 var keyDocumentResponse = _repo.GetKeyDocument(new KeyDocumentRequest() { KeyDocumentId = request.KeyDocumentId });
```

and

```
  Customization[] customizations = GenerateCustomizationsForKeyDocument(keyDocumentDetails.KeyDocumentId, keyDocumentResponse);
```

Then

```
    public KeyDocumentProofResponse ProofKeyDocument(KeyDocumentProofRequest request)
    {
        //return new KeyDocumentProofResponse()
        //{
        //    data = new KeyDocumentProofResponseData() { JobId = "2984" }
        //};
        KeyDocumentProofResponse response = new KeyDocumentProofResponse();
        var keyDocumentDetails = _repo.GetKeyDocument(new KeyDocumentRequest() { KeyDocumentId = request.KeyDocumentId }).data;
        if (keyDocumentDetails != null && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyDocumentDetails.CampaignId)) &&
                keyDocumentDetails.DesignFileId.HasValue &&
                keyDocumentDetails.DesignFileId > 0)
        {

            var keyDocumentResponse = _repo.GetKeyDocument(new KeyDocumentRequest() { KeyDocumentId = request.KeyDocumentId });

            Customization[] customizations = GenerateCustomizationsForKeyDocument(keyDocumentDetails.KeyDocumentId, keyDocumentResponse);

            var jobTicketId = _uproduceRepo.CreateJobTicket(keyDocumentDetails.DocumentId, keyDocumentDetails.DataSourceId, "PROOF");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobTicketId))
            {
                List<JobDataSource> dataSources = GenerateCSVForPersonalizedAndCustomizedVariables(keyDocumentResponse, jobTicketId);

                var jobId = _uproduceRepo.ProduceDocument(keyDocumentDetails.DocumentId, keyDocumentDetails.DataSourceId, customizations, "PROOF", jobTicketId, dataSources);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobId))
                {
                    response.Error = CreateCustomError("Error while submitting job", "Error occurred while submitting proofing job");
                }
                else
                {
                    response.data.JobId = jobId;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                response.Error = CreateCustomError("Unable to generate job ticket for the keydocument",
                "Error while creating a job ticket for proof request");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            response.Error = CreateCustomError("Unable to generate proof for the keydocument",
                "Requested template is missing campaignid or Designfile in Uproduce");
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Well presumably `k.Type` is null, or `k` is null.

Comment: thx,   when are you going to hit a million points... i'm still waiting   hehe    thx Jon

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right code for the `ProofKeyDocument` method?  That method you posted has a different name and takes different parameters.

Comment: updating question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Published test doesn't contain mock method for "CreteJobTicket" and jobTickedId will be null.

```
var jobTicketId = _uproduceRepo.CreateJobTicket(keyDocumentDetails.DocumentId, keyDocumentDetails.DataSourceId, "PROOF");
```